Okhttp caching system not working 504 Unsatisfiable Request (only-if-cached)
I want to cache 200 requests and retrive data from cache when don't have internet/meet some api errors, but cannot get any data from cache:
My network interceptor
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
val request = chain.request()
val originalResponse = chain.proceed(request)

// Only cache responses with status code 200
if (originalResponse.code == 200) {
    val cacheResponse =  originalResponse.newBuilder()
        .header(
            name = HeadersFields.CACHE_CONTROL,
            value = HeadersFields.getPublicMaxAgeHeader(cacheTimeInSecond = 3600
            )
        )
        .removeHeader(name = HeadersFields.PRAGMA)
        .build()
    return cacheResponse
}

return originalResponse
}

App interceptor
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
val request = chain.request()

val cacheRequest =
    request.newBuilder().cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_CACHE).removeHeader(name = HeadersFields.PRAGMA).build()

return try {
    chain.proceed(request)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    when (e) {
        is ServerError, is SocketTimeoutException, is TimeoutException, is ConnectException -> {
            chain.proceed(cacheRequest)
        }
        else -> chain.proceed(request)
    }
}
}

I inject okhttp client instance to both interceptors in order to monitor cache and I see records (that increase after next requests)

But I got

(httpStatusCode=504, httpMessage=Unsatisfiable Request (only-if-cached), responseBody=)
Blockquote

My client ( Ive got only one OkHttpClient that inject everywhere). I set up maxRequestsPerHost to 1 to avoid race condition, but it doesn't help :/
private const val CONNECT_TIMEOUT_SEC = 60L
private const val CACHE_MAX_SIZE = 50L * 1024L * 1024L

    fun getOkHttpClient(context: Context): OkHttpClient {
        val appCache = Cache(directory = context.cacheDir, maxSize = CACHE_MAX_SIZE)
        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
            cache(appCache)
            connectTimeout(timeout = CONNECT_TIMEOUT_SEC, unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        }.build()
        client.dispatcher.maxRequestsPerHost = 1
        return client
    }


You might want to put a breakpoint in OkHttp’s internal CacheStrategy class which decides whether a cached response satisfies a request.

Thanks for the response, that help a little. It seems that this specific response cannot be save to cache due to race condition (my idea?) and it doesn't save anything for this specyfic endpoint.
here is the part when its broke
package okhttp3.internal.cache

class DiskLruCache internal constructor(
  internal val fileSystem: FileSystem,

  /** Returns the directory where this cache stores its data. */
  val directory: File,

  private val appVersion: Int,

  internal val valueCount: Int,

  /** Returns the maximum number of bytes that this cache should use to store its data. */
  maxSize: Long,

  /** Used for asynchronous journal rebuilds. */
  taskRunner: TaskRunner
) 
  /** Returns an editor for the entry named [key], or null if another edit is in progress. */
  @Synchronized @Throws(IOException::class)
  @JvmOverloads
  fun edit(key: String, expectedSequenceNumber: Long = ANY_SEQUENCE_NUMBER): Editor? {
    initialize()

    checkNotClosed()
    validateKey(key)
    var entry: Entry? = lruEntries[key]
    if (expectedSequenceNumber != ANY_SEQUENCE_NUMBER &&
        (entry == null || entry.sequenceNumber != expectedSequenceNumber)) {
      return null // Snapshot is stale.
    }

    if (entry?.currentEditor != null) {
      return null // Another edit is in progress.
    }

entry?.currentEditor is not null and request cannot be saved...
